# Copy a file only if last modify is less than 10 minutes

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, copy

I currently have this batch-file that automatically backups a file every 10 minutes if firefox is open. But I would like the .bat to actually copy only if the last modified time of my file (zotero.sqlite) is less than 10 minutes:

**In details**

11:00 AM  I run the bat, with my current code, a backup is automatically created. 
I leave my desk for 30 minutes (so no modification is made to the zotero.sqlite during that time). Meanwhile, the .bat timeout will have created 3 copies of zotero.sqlite (at 11:10, 11:20 and 11:30). But I don't want those copies because they will all be identical (they will all have the same last modified date/time). 
 Instead I would like the .bat to be "intelligent" and notice that the files are the same (because the last modified date is the same for all) and only copy the file if the last modified date is different.

Because my simple .bat doesn't keep track of the last time it did a copy, the easiest way for it to determine if the zotero.sqlite was modified is to check the last modify date and see if it's more than 10 minutes ago :

● if yes, then the bat should not copy the zotero.sqlite and restart the 10 minutes timeout

● if the last modified date/time is less than 10 minutes ago, the bat should copy and then start the 10 minutes timeout

This will prevent me from having hundreds of identical backups accumulating.

```
@echo off
set programName=firefox.exe
start %programName%
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %programName%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%programName%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" copy "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\Working_on_zotero_%date%---%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sqlite"
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" exit /b
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
goto loop
```

I tried the /d command but it's giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Not quite following your explanation.  You have a TIMEOUT of 10 minutes.  So you will only get a backup every 10 minutes. Not sure what you mean by **inferior** to 10 minutes.  If you want it to backup every 10 minutes, have it only backup if the archive attribute is set.  The archive attribute is set every time a file has changed.  So this would require you to use the `XCOPY` command instead. So after 10 minutes if the file has not changed the archive attribute will not be set and XCOPY will not copy the file.

Comment: Thanks @Squashman. I have added the "in details" part. I think you got what I mean: if I understood you, I should simply change the `copy` in my ode into a `xcopy`?

Comment: If you read the help for the `XCOPY` command will also notice the `/M` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

this now works with regular copy so it won't prompt anymore, uses the archive attribute to check if a file has been edited, and then removes that attribute after the copy

```
@echo off
set programName=firefox.exe
start %programName%
:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %programName%" 2>NUL | find /I /N "%programName%">NUL
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" goto copy
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" exit /b
:delayloop
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
goto loop

:copy
set "LogFile=C:\Users\Me\Zotero\zotero.sqlite"
attrib "%LogFile%" | findstr /B /L A 1>nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto delayloop
copy "%LogFile%" "C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\Working_on_zotero_%date%---%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sqlite"
echo File "%LogFile%" was modified since last check.
attrib -A "%LogFile%"
goto delayloop
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis! I tried you suggestion but I get this when I run the .bat and after each timeout : `Does C:\Users\Me\Zotero\Zotero_Backup_sqlite\Working_on_zotero_2015-11-26--- 6_44_58.sqlite specify a file name or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)?`
Is there a way to automatically choose F, because I would like the backup to run in background (without me having each 10 minutes to hit F)? Maybe this have to do with the fact that I rename the file during the backup?

Comment: Updated my answer to not prompt anymore

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot Dennis!